# SQL QUERY IN PHP, can i combine them?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a SQL query inside my PHP that returns a table with products that have not been completed. But for the query to execute I have to manually type in the onrow number to make the query exucute. But I have a second query what return all the results for products with a delivery date for tomorrow. So how can I make the first query to get the onrow number from the second query to take the result of the second query and print the table with tomorrows products onrow number which are not completed.

Here is the code for first query in php:

```
<?php
$otsitav=$_POST['tid'];
$qryType=$_POST['qryType'];
$db=new mysqli('192.168.1.35','root','','newpms');
if($qryType=="works"){
$msc=microtime(true);
$result=$db->query($query);
$num_results=$result->num_rows;
if($num_results>0){
echo '<table border="1" class="db-table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="16%">Aeg</th>
<th width="6%">ID</th>
<th width="8%">Liin</th>
<th width="47%">Toode</th>
<th width="15%">Alus</th>
<th width="8%">Arv</th>
<th width="8%">Töötaja</th>
</thead>
<tbody>';
for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++){
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo '<tr>
<td>'.$row['timestamp'].'</td>
<td>'.$row['idnr'].'</td>
<td>'.$row['prLine'].'</td>
<td>'.utf8_encode($row['glass']).'</td>
<td>'.$row['rack'].'</td>
<td>'.$row['qty'].'</td>
<td>'.utf8_encode($row['fullName']).'</td>
</tr>';
}
echo "</tbody></table>";}

else{
    echo "<h2>Puudub info sellise toote kohta</h2>";
    }
$msc=microtime(true)-$msc;
echo "Kestus:".round($msc,2)." sec";
$result->free();
}
if($qryType=="rowStat"){
$msc=microtime(true);
$query="select proddb.onrrnr,proddb.idnr,proddb.onr,proddb.prod,proddb.qty from proddb WHERE proddb.onr=".$otsitav." AND proddb.idnr<>'0'";
$result=$db->query($query);
$num_results=$result->num_rows;
if($num_results>0){
    echo '<table border="1" class="db-table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="">Tellimus</th>
<th width="6">ID</th>
<th width="8">Toode</th>
<th width="">Valmis</th>
</thead>
<tbody>';
    for ($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++){
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $query1="SELECT p1.onrrnr, p1.prLineSh, p1.glLiteNr, p1.seqNr, p1.planQty FROM pf_prodQtySeq p1 INNER JOIN (SELECT onrrnr, glLiteNr, MAX(seqNr) AS seqNr FROM pf_prodQtySeq  where onrrnr=".$row['onrrnr']." GROUP BY  glLiteNr) p2 ON p2.glLiteNr = p1.glLiteNr AND p2.seqNr = p1.seqNr AND p2.onrrnr=p1.onrrnr";
        $result1=$db->query($query1);
          $qtyMultiplier=1;
        $num_results1=$result1->num_rows; 
        if($num_results1>0){
            $liteOrdQty=0;
            $remQty=0;
            for ($i1=0; $i1 <$num_results1; $i1++){ 
                if($num_results1>1){
                 $qtyMultiplier=$num_results1;
            }
                $row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc();
                $liteOrdQty=$liteOrdQty+$row['qty'];
                $remQty=$remQty+$row1['planQty'];
            }
            $liteOrdQty=$liteOrdQty/$qtyMultiplier;
            $remQty=$remQty/$qtyMultiplier;
            $doneQty=($liteOrdQty-$remQty);
        }
        if($liteOrdQty===$remQty){
            echo '<tr style="font-weight:bold">
        <td>'.$row['onr'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['idnr'].'</td>
        <td>'.utf8_encode($row['prod']).'</td>
        <td style = "color:red">'.$liteOrdQty."/".$doneQty.'</td>
        </tr>';
        }
    }
}
}
$db->close();
?>
```

The second witch gets me tomorrows date delivery products :

```
$sql = "SELECT CURDATE(),`onrrnr`, `deldate`, `cusref1` \n"
    . "FROM `proddb`\n"
    . "WHERE `deldate` = CURDATE()+1\n"
    . "ORDER BY `proddb`.`deldate` ASC";
```

Can i some how make them work and combine them ?
Thank you!

[Shema for third query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8OGg.png)

[Shema for second and first query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYsoe.png)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'onrow number' and what makes this more difficult is that there's no 'onrow number' in your code. Ah, I see, you abbreviate that to `onrrnr`... May I ask why?! Do not abbreviate names unnecessarily, it makes your code harder to read.

Comment: Can you post both queries?

Comment: Add an extra clause to your `WHERE`, so you filter out the products that are done. Something like `WHERE  deldate = CURDATE()+1  AND orderstatus = 0`

Comment: @KIKO Software : They have a whole database this way, full of  abbreviation, i cant really do nothing about it, got to work with it..

Comment: @SuperKevin : the other queries are in the php as $query and $query1.

Comment: @Michel: that didnt help cause, this query gets me the result i need first, and the second query is for the end result, witch i would like to take in the first result and go through it, to produse me the end result of products not done.
Thank you all for help though.

Comment: This is really hard to read. What if you post the two tables schemas and then tell us the requirement? Maybe we can figure it out. But deciphering these queries without data is hard, at least for me.

Comment: @SuperKevin 
SELECT CURDATE(),`onrrnr`, `deldate`, `cusref1` 
    FROM `proddb`
   WHERE `deldate` = CURDATE()+1
   ORDER BY `proddb`.`deldate` ASC;

:should be the input into the second query and third query.
Right now the manual input to the second query also goes through the third.
It should take first 7n number from the "onrrnr" filed as its input.
If it could take the first query result as an input to those, i should get the complete list i need, without have to typing it. I need it to make that execute once a day automaticly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple mysql queries in PHP like this :

```
$sql= "SELECT p1.onrrnr, p1.prLineSh, p1.glLiteNr, p1.seqNr, p1.planQty FROM pf_prodQtySeq p1 INNER JOIN (SELECT onrrnr, glLiteNr, MAX(seqNr) AS seqNr FROM pf_prodQtySeq  where onrrnr=".$row['onrrnr']." GROUP BY  glLiteNr) p2 ON p2.glLiteNr = p1.glLiteNr AND p2.seqNr = p1.seqNr AND p2.onrrnr=p1.onrrnr;";
$sql.= "SELECT CURDATE(),`onrrnr`, `deldate`, `cusref1` "FROM `proddb` WHERE `deldate` = CURDATE()+1 "ORDER BY `proddb`.`deldate` ASC;";
```

Comment: Yes, but i dont get the result i need in this way, i somehow need to join the first(in your response $sql.) results to the secon query, i quess they should be assosietaed to this [where onrrnr=".$row['onrrnr']." ] set.

And in this the results should act as input to the field ;
[WHERE proddb.onr=".$otsitav."]

$query="select proddb.onrrnr,proddb.idnr,proddb.onr,proddb.prod,proddb.qty from proddb WHERE proddb.onr=".$otsitav." AND proddb.idnr<>'0'";

Thank you for the effort though.